# SELECT * FROM table HUNDREDS MILLIONS ROWS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Okay so I have a table which currently has 40000 rows and I need to `SELECT` them all. I use a index for `id` and `url` column and if I have to `SELECT` a value by `id` or `url` it's instant but if I have to `SELECT *` it's very slow. What I'm trying to do is searching my database and output the matches and I did this with a

```
while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
     { #code... echo $arr['whatever_i_need']."<br>"; }
```

`$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table");`

In the future I will have hundreds of millions of rows in the database so I would like to return the search results fast in 1 sec or something. If you can give me solutions I would really appreciate! Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I don't want to display all of the data but I want to loop through it quickly to find all the matches

Comment: If you're trying to return hundreds of millions of results to display to a user in one page, then you're going to annoy a lot of users; no user is going to wade through a page displaying hundreds of millions of rows, even if you could display the page quickly..... use paging at the very least, and provide searching for them to see the records they're interested in

Comment: You're returning *all of the data in the table*.  More data will go slower than less data.  There's really no way around that.  Indexes don't mean anything when you're *selecting every row*.

Comment: and if you're planning to have that huge database switch to some NoSQL solution like Elasticsearch

Comment: you should expect slow response especially when you are selecting them all, what you can possibly do is `paginate` or `batch` the select query, take 50 now for 1 query, next query is skip the first 50.. and so on.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that I don't want to display all that data but I have to loop through it to find the matches.

Comment: @CosminCiocan: You might want to look up the `WHERE` keyword in SQL.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%value%'  LIMIT 0,100`
pagination, for page 2 would be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%value%'  LIMIT 101,100`

Comment: If I opened a website and thousands of millions of rows popped up I'd never enter this website again.

Comment: Pass the matches into your query, not after you've retrieved all of the rows. You'll get rid of a lot of overhead that way.

Comment: If you only want to return selected records, then you use a WHERE clause in your SQL query, and make sure that your table is sensibly indexed.... this is what databases do for a living, and are very good at!

Comment: seems a bit of confusion.. `SELECT * ` does not imply select every "row"  it means select all "columns" from a record. The lack of a "WHERE" and/or LIMIT clause is why you are getting every record.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that that's not what I wanted to say. The thing I am trying to do is sorting the results from my db for example a user searches stack overflow and I loop through my database and see what I can get and display it very quickly that's what I want.

Comment: Then you'd write your query with a "WHERE" and an "ORDER BY"    That's what databases are for. It makes no sense to fetch the entire database then loop through it looking for matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed then you definitely don't want the query to return *every* row from the table, and then "loop through" every row returned by the query to identify the ones you are interested in returning. That approach might give acceptable performance with small tables, but it definitely doesn't scale.

For performance, you want the database to locate just the rows you want to return, filter out the ones you don't want, and return just the subset.

And that comes down to writing an appropriate SQL query; executing an appropriate SELECT statement.

```
SELECT t.col1
     , t.col2
     , t.col3
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.col3 LIKE '%foo%'
   AND t.col2 >= '2016-03-15'
   AND t.col2 <  '2016-06-15'
 ORDER BY t.col2 DESC, t.col1 DESC
 LIMIT 200
```

Performance is about making sure appropriate indexes are available and that the query execution is making effective use of the available indexes.